# Docker Service as an endpoint that exposes a WCF service that receives parameters with many replicas

Tags: docker, wcf, docker-swarm

I'm new to docker containers, so excuse me if I'm asking something that's been solved before, but I couldn't find any information related to this specific question.

I have already created a custom image that has everything ready for a WCF service to run without problems.Also, I have already run a container where I published the service to a local port and everything works fine. Because I need that service to be scaled up and down as per the number of requests received, I proceed to create a Docker Service so I could create replicas of that service in a Docker Swarm, and the service could be scaled up and down as desired. But when I create the service using the same image as before, I can't get it to work, and kept receiving the next error:

[image]

The command line I use is the next one:

```
docker service create --name=SWARM_OCR_SERVICE --endpoint-mode dnsrr --network=SWARM_NETWORK_OCR ocrserviceimage:v7 --publish 2019:2020 --replicas 5
```

What I thought the Docker Service would do is to create as many containers that were running the specified image as the number of replicas specified on its creation, and also, if specified, publish that service so you can make requests to that local port (Docker Service endpoint) and then the requests were routed accordingly between all of those replicas.

What I'm trying to achieve is to expose many replicas of a container that has a WCF service that recieve parameters, so clients can make requests to that endpoint, and the number of containers alive at any given moment can be scaled up or down as needed. Am I doing it as expected? Am I understanding it correctly? What I want to do is possible the way I want to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it. Docker containers are required to have always an EntryPoint to keep alive the container. The image I am using to create my containers (the oficial WCF image from Microsoft Hub) has as the EntryPoint an executable file calles ServiceMonitor.exe, that monitors an IIS service. For some reasons still unknown to me, that service is failing only when the service is the one that creates the containers within it. If I run a container outside of the service, it runs fine. So I overwrote the WCF image's EntryPoint and set my own. Now the containers and replicas inside the service are alive and running all the time.

Tl;dr As long as a container's EntryPoint process is running, the container is going to be alive. If it stops, the container stops too.